# Translation of "cash flow management"

Tags: translation, english-to-german

How would you translate "cash flow management" into German?

I specifically refer to the process of tracking a **small business** or **freelancer** income and expenses on a daily basis to make sure the bank account is not going to be negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the English sentence `Cash-Flow-Management`.

You may also use `Liquiditätsrechnung` or `Liquiditätsmanagement` if you prefer a more German term.

Comment: Sorry, but you are wrong. "Liquiditätsrechnung" is "liquidity calculation". Liquidity is not the same as cash flow, and management is not the same as calculation! The best "translation" of "cash flow" is "Cashflow". If you hate anglizismns in german language, you might use "Geldumlauf" or "Finanzmittelfluss" (which are not very common). Take a look at german wikipedia: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cashflow vs. http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquidität

Answer (score 3):

**DO NOT TRANSLATE TECHNICAL TERMS!**

"Cashflow" or "Cash-Flow" is in economics-German much more common than any translation. If you translate terms like those into german and use them among managers, those managers might think you are untaught. They will not tell you, but they will ignore what you say.

Comment: I guess you're right, and your advice is sound if you need those managers think well of you. However, if that's not important, then using _appropriate_ translations is recommendable.

Comment: so would you recommend using "cash-flow-management" ?

Comment: @NightOwl: Not exactly, but you are very close. Allways use uppercase letters for 1st letter of a noun in german context, even if the word itself is english. So "Cash-Flow-Management", "Cashflow-Management" and "Cashflowmanagement" are the correct terms in a german context dealing with economics. I would prefere "Cashflow-Management".

Comment: +1 for the extra hyphen in "Cashflow-Management". Just because you *can* build huge words in German doesn't mean you should do it.